# Calendar.app: disable event-specific alerts while retaining calendar-wide alerts

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I would like to essentially move all of my calendar alerts to appear 5 minutes before the event, rather than the time chosen by the event creator (typically 10 minutes). Is there a way to achieve this with Calendar.app?

I can configure an extra alert in this menu for 5 minutes before:
[image: alerts settings menu]

However, the event-specific alert is still shown. Selecting 'Ignore alerts' in the calendar info will ignore all alerts, even the configured 5 minute alerts in the settings panel:
[image: ignore alerts checkbox]

How can I receive only a 5 minute alert for all events?

Answer (score 0):

- In Calendar.app go to View -> Show Calendar List and turn off all the other calendars that you don't want to affect.
- Then select the remaining calendar and go to File -> Export and export that calendar to .ics file
- Open the .ics file in a text editor such as Visual Studio Code.
- Replace all the TRIGGER:-P10M with TRIGGER:-P5M
  This will change all the 10 minute before event alarms on the calendar to be 5 minutes before the event.
  This will not affect any alerts that were set as (default) so if they were set at the system default they will continue to obey the system defaults that you set.
- Save the file
- (optional) create a new test calendar that's blank with no appointments.
- import into Calendar.app onto the desired calendar.

Comment: This will not make an impact on newly created events after the process. Is there a way to make this permanent? This solution seems like a last resort